# Is DynamoDB the right option for this use case?

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, bigdata, amazon-dynamodb

I want to love DynamoDB, but the major drawback is the query/scan on the whole DB to pull the results for one query. Would I be better sicking with MySQL or is there another solution I should be aware of?

Uses:

- Newsfeed items (Pulls most recent items from table where id in x,x,x,x,x)
- User profiles relationships (users follow and friend eachother)
- User lists (users can have up to 1,000 items in one list)

I am happy to mix and match database solutions.The main use is lists.

There will be a few million lists eventually, ranging from 5 to 1000 items per list. The list table is formatted as follows: list_id(bigint)|order(int(1))|item_text(varchar(500))|item_text2(varchar(12))|timestamp(int(11))

The main queries on this DB would be on the 'list_relations' table:

> Select 'item_text' from lists where list_id=539830

I suppose my main question. Can we get all items for a particular list_id, without a slow query/scan? and by 'slow' do people mean a second? or a few minutes?

Thank you

Comment: Hash Key = list_id, Range Key = timestamp => query (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LowLevelPHPQuerying.html) with milliseconds response

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to address whether or not it's a good choice or the right choice, but you can do what you're asking. I have a large dynamoDB instance with vehicle VINs as the Hash, something else for my range, and I have a secondary index on vin and a timestamp field, I am able to make fast queries over thousands of records for specific vehicles over timestamp searches, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Constructing your schema in DynamoDB requires different considerations than building in MySQL.

You want to avoid scans as much as possible, this means picking your hash key carefully.

Depending on your exact queries, you may also need to have multiple tables that have the same data..but with different hashkeys depending on your querying needs.

You also did not mention the LSI and GSI features of DynamoDB, these also help your query-ability, but have their own sets of drawbacks. It is difficult to advise further without knowing more details about your requirements.